# JTable header alignment

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I would like to set the vertical alignment of the label in the header of my JTable-derrived class.

I am aware of `setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);`

My header is much higher than the font and I would like to place the text **slightly below** the vertical centre.

How can I do this, without overriding `paint()` ?

THX

Comment: that's not possible, the layout of a JLabel is rather fixed. What you might try is setting an invisible icon of appropriate size and set the text position to be below the icon. Beware: that'll clash with sort markers, as most LAFs use the icon as such.

Comment: forgot the usual for unusual requirements: why?

Comment: Because attention to such tiny details make things looks better. Sometimes you need to think like a graphic designer, not a programmer :)

Comment: then you'll probably end writing an entire LAF :-) Or find one, commercial or free, there are several looking quite polished - _with_ attention to detail

Comment: BTW, what is your target LAF?

Comment: Kleo, It's windows for the moment, but we plan on improving upon it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

one of ways is to set `Renderer`, `TableHeader` by default returns `JLabel`, for example

```
  final TableCellRenderer tcrOs = myTable.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
       myTable.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, 
                   Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, 
                   int row, int column) {
                JLabel lbl = (JLabel) tcrOs.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, 
                      value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                lbl.setForeground(AppVariables.textColor);
                lbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(lbl.getBorder(), 
                      BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 0, 0)));
                lbl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
                if (isSelected) {
                    lbl.setForeground(Color.red);
                    lbl.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                } else {
                    lbl.setForeground(Color.blue);
                    lbl.setBackground(Color.black);
                }
                return lbl;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks mKobel! kleo it IS related. The trick I needed is burried in there. All I needed was:        setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(getBorder(), BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(6, 0, 0, 0)));

Comment: okay, I stand corrected, actually overlooked that line in all the clutter ;-)

Comment: Still a lot of random code to simply add a Border to a renderer. Sometimes it is hard to see the tree through the forest because you always add so much unnecessary code.

Answer (score 2):

```
JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
TableCellRenderer renderer = header.getDefaultRenderer();
renderer.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: This is NOT an answer to my question. Read the question more carefully.

Comment: @Adam, I read the question 3 times. I still posted what I thought was the answer you where looking for. Usually I can read read between the lines for a poorly worded question, but I guess not this time. Next time post a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) so we don't have to guess.

Comment: There's no method `setVerticalAlignment()` in the `TableCellRenderer` interface. The renderer has to be cast to `DefaultTableCellRenderer`.

Comment: setVerticalAlignment cannot be found. thus code isn't Not working