# JTableHeader table header cell border

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, jtableheader

I am using this code:

```
Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green); 
DefaulTableModel dtm= new DefaultTableModel();
dtm.addColumn("Srno.");
dtm.addColumn("Product");
JTable table = new JTable(dtm);
table.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(150,255,150));
JTableHeader hed = table.getTableHeader();
hed.setBorder(border);
```

I want to add border for each cell of the `tableheader`. Is there any method to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set [TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for [TableHeader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#headertooltip), for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8524133/714968) or [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1060__JTableHeader.htm)