# how do you left-align text in JTableHeader?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, renderer, jtableheader

I've tried the following,

```
foo.getTableHeader().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

where `foo` is the `JTable` instance, but the text remains centered. Why?

Comment: [setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8524133/714968)

Comment: @mKorbel, which component would you set this on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code affects where the table header itself is positioned, not the items within each header.  You need to call `getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(xxx)` with something that left-aligns the types you care about.

Comment: i wrote a class that implemented the `TableCellRenderer` interface.

Answer (score 1):

```
((DefaultTableCellRenderer)table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT)
```

The easiest way I found working for me. Of course, you can use another centering constant for `JLabel.LEFT`.